# Quotes in a jquery statement

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to append using jquery a text of a hidden field and a Action link
here is the code:

```
$('#tabla').append('<tr><td>$('#name')</td><td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit")</td>/tr>)';
```

I'm having a issue with the quotes in name and the @

What I have to do to solve this kind of issues when I have this characters in a jquery statement?

Comment: You can't use a single quote inside single quotes, escape it with \ also you have syntax problems after <td> why there is $() there?

Comment: The $() is a reference to a hidden field: `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ListProducts[model.ListProducts.Count()].ProductName, new {id = "name"})`

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$('#tabla').append('<tr><td>'+$("#name")+'</td><td>@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit")</td>/tr>');
```